# Stow to destination root /: existing target is not owned by stow

Tags: stow

I'm trying to stow a package to the "root" `/`

```
# cd ~/.dotfiles
# sudo stow -t / kraken
WARNING! stowing kraken would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is not owned by stow: lib
All operations aborted.
```

My package looks like  this:

```
kraken
├── home
│   └── user
│       └── scripts
├── lib
│   └── systemd
│       └── system
│           └── some.service
```

Can stow help me out with this or am I not using it as is supposed?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't immediately think why this wouldn't work.  Try re-running with `-v3` or `-v4` to see if that sheds any light.

Comment: Hah! with -v4 I found that /lib was actually a symlink to /usr/lib! Took that into consideration and everything went smooth. Please add this as an asnwer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, running with `-v4` revealed that `/lib` was actually a symlink to `/usr/lib`.  This is similar  but probably not identical to https://github.com/aspiers/stow/issues/11.